# Background image does not display on iOS

Tags: html, css, background-image

The following code works fine to display 1 of possible 4 background images with a corresponding background color on desktop browsers (see [methodally.com](http://methodally.com/)). However on iOS, the image only appears when the background is white. When a color background is presented, the image does not appear. All images are the roughly the same size. Any thoughts?

**Update**: Also tried switching the order of the arrays. No luck. Even when the white background and associated image are last in the array, this is the only combination that appears on iOS.

Here is my `index.php` file:

```
<?php
$bl = array('logo-white.png', 'logo-pink.png', 'logo-blue.png', 'logo-teal.png' ); 
$bc = array('#fdfdfe', '#b0265d', '#040442', '#43a5ae' ); 
$i = rand(0, count($bl)-1); // generate random number size of the array
$selectedBl = "$bl[$i]"; // set variable equal to which random filename was chosen
$selectedBc = "$bc[$i]"; // set variable equal to corresponding background color
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<style type="text/css">
html { 
   width:100%; 
   height:100%; 
   background: <?php echo $selectedBc; ?> url(/img/<?php echo $selectedBl; ?>) center center no-repeat;
   background-size:60%;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [(Really) Long Background Image Does Not Render on iPad Safari](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9046143/really-long-background-image-does-not-render-on-ipad-safari)

Comment: thanks, @Pete. i read something similar, but in my case, all images are the same size (in kb and pixels). so i don't know why only the image associated with the white background will display.

Comment: I would use a media query to load a smaller image if the screen size isn't too large - not sure who has a screen resolution of 4000px so you may want to make them smaller anyway. not sure why your white one would work

Comment: reducing from 4000w to 2000w did the trick, but i am not sure why. the white version displayed on iOS at 4000w.

Comment: weird, could be some sort of colour rendering issue with large pngs but that's just a complete guess!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Pete: I would use a media query to load a smaller image if the screen size isn't too large - not sure who has a screen resolution of 4000px so you may want to make them smaller anyway. not sure why your white one would work

Me: reducing from 4000w to 2000w did the trick, but i am not sure why. the white version displayed on iOS at 4000w.

Comment: [No mystery as to why](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14227678/background-image-will-not-show-on-ios-but-shows-fine-on-other-browsers/15034916#15034916)

Comment: thanks, @steveax. i understand why reducing works given the specs, but i don't know why one version of the image with a white background would appear even at 4000w.

Comment: One color == lower bit depth.